# Can references be used to implement function overriding?

Tags: c++

Can references be used to implement function overriding? 
Can I have a base-class reference that points to a derived-class object, and then get the feature of late binding?

Comment: In general, the answer is that, yes, you can.  However, I assume that you have a concrete example of failing code, or you would not have asked the question.  Consider adding the example to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The reason is that, in C++, the derived class object contains a hidden pointer to a record that details the object's actual type.  Both the pointer and the record remain, even when a reference binds the object in question.

This assumes, as @Simon observes, that you have declared the function virtual in the base class.  (Otherwise, the needed hidden pointer does not exist.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but polymorphism isn't automatic the way it is in some languages like Java. You have to declare the function `virtual` in the base class.

Comment: yes that anyways is the case with pointer as well. functions in C++ are not by default virtual, as compared to many other language.